# Check if this date transcend one minute of new date

Tags: java

Problem
how can i do a condition that check if dateReservation transcend  one minute of new date!!!

Code

```
    Adresse entity = adresseDao.findOne(id);
    entity.setStatut("RESERVER");
    entity.setDateReservation(new Date()); 
    Date date1 = entity.getDateReservation();
    Date date2 = new Date();

    entity.setReserverPar(secUtilisateurService.getCurrentUser());
    adresseDao.save(entity);
```

Comment: Hi. If you are using LocalDateTime, you can do it as: `date1.isAfter(currentDate)` where `date1` is the date that is `currentDate.plusMinutes(1)`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(date1.getTime() >= (date2.getTime() + TimeUnit.MINUTES.toMillis(1))){
 ....
}
```

could be a simple approach. This basically checks the reservation time is equal or greater than 1 minute after current time. The comparison is done on milliseconds.

There could be more ways to do this, depending on the libraries and java version you have.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
try {
        SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_YYYY_MM_ddTHH_MM_SS_Z);
        Date date1 = fmt.parse(entity.getDateReservation());
        Date date2  = new Date();

        // Calculates the difference in milliseconds.
        long millisDiff = nowDate.getTime() - date1.getTime();
        int minutes = (int) (millisDiff / 60000 % 60);

        if( minutes<1 && minutes>=0)
            return true;
        else
            //what you want if false;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        // log exception
    }
```

...it could also be convenient to write the possible exception in a log. Hi!

Comment: thank you so much that's what I did   Date date1 = adresse.getDateReservation();
  Date date2  = new Date();
  long millisDiff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
  long minutes = (long) (millisDiff / (60000));
  if(minutes > 1){
   adresse.setStatut(EnumStatutAdresse.LIBRE.toString());
   adresse.setReserverPar(null);
  }
  adresseDao.save(adresse);

Answer (score 0):

```
    // thank you so much That's what I did

Date date1 = adresse.getDateReservation();
        Date date2  = new Date();
        long millisDiff = (date2.getTime() - date1.getTime());
        long minutes = (long) (millisDiff / (60000));
        if(minutes > 1){
            adresse.setStatut(EnumStatutAdresse.LIBRE.toString());
            adresse.setReserverPar(null);
        }
        adresseDao.save(adresse);
```